# Set Image in imagePickerController with using Kingfisher

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimage, kingfisher

I want to set image to my `UIImageView` in `imagePickerController` with using `Kingfisher` but nothing happens. First i direct the user to the photo library. After the user selects the photo and comes back, i get the photo as `UIImage` and the an `URL` in `imagePickerController`. Kingfisher does not have a method to set `UIImage`. So i try to set it from URL but i just see empty an `UIImageView`. My code is;

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let changedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! URL


    profilePhotoImage.kf.setImage(with: url)

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

My url is,  `"assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=D21C7124-472A-44F8-A22B-B3A5A0C48E32&ext=JPG" 0x00000001702f7680"`. Is there anything wrong with my URL or can i set `UIImage` with kingfisher.  I'm sure i can get the photo because when i try to set that `changedImage` without `kf` it works. I tried the
 [Kingfisher and swift 3 - cannot set image with url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40793674/kingfisher-and-swift-3-cannot-set-image-with-url) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you are right. It is really so strange.

Try to set your changed image on picker dismiss method's completion. maybe it will work:

```
picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
 self.imageView.image = self.changedImage
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do this on completion handler along with the main thread

```
  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {


    dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.imgProfile.kf.base.image = image
            }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried doenloading from a local URL, but I'm sure there's a way to download an image using Kingfisher.

Use ImageDownloader to download an image without caching

```
ImageDownloader.default.downloadImage(with: url, options: [], progressBlock: nil) { 
(image, error, url, data) in 
    print("Downloaded Image: \(image)")
}
```

You can refer to this cheat sheet.

https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet

Comment: Yeah there must be an easy way to set image with kingfisher. I checked the cheat sheet but i couldn't find. It is so strange.

Comment: In which context you would like to use `Kingfisher`? Is it for the caching functionality?

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 5
You can try this code:

let addURL = "https://..."

```
    if let urlPhotos = URL(string: addURL) {
        image.kf.setImage(with: urlPhotos, placeholder: UIImage(systemName: "folder"))
```

Make sure you declared  @IBOutlet to UIImageView.

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer so that the next user knows why this solution worked for you.